# CSS sidebar over the whole height

Tags: css

I'm having problems with the height tag.

I want to make a sidebar that has the background extended to the bottom of the page.

I've set the height to 100% but this doesn't work like I tought it would.

This is my code for the side bar.

```
#side{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    background-color: white;
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff; 
    text-align: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You have to set height 100% to his parent and don´t forget to also set body and html to 100% of height

Comment: I have used vh which works.

Comment: vh is a viewport unit, so it only expands on the viewport (screen size). If you have the need to make scroll of the page, that will not work (not expand all page)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you'll need to make the sidebar absolute positioned, inside of a relative wrapping tag, something like the body. Then use padding at the same width of your sidebar on the element's that are going to display next to it.

As an example:

```css
header {
  background: red
}
section {
  background: yellow
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
}
aside {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid green 2px;
}
article {
  padding-left: 240px;
  border: solid orange 2px;
}
footer {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>header</h1>
</header>
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <aside>sidebar</aside>
    <article>
      <h1>A Clone of My Own</h1> 
      <p>OK, this has gotta stop. I'm going to remind Fry of his humanity the way only a woman can. I love this planet! I've got wealth, fame, and access to the depths of sleaze that those things bring. Bender, I didn't know you liked cooking. That's so
        cute. If rubbin' frozen dirt in your crotch is wrong, hey I don't wanna be right. And from now on you're all named Bender Jr. And why did 'I' have to take a cab?</p>
      <h2>The Sting</h2> 
      <p>Guards! Bring me the forms I need to fill out to have her taken away! Too much work. Let's burn it and say we dumped it in the sewer. You're going to do his laundry? Yep, I remember. They came in last at the Olympics, then retired to promote alcoholic
        beverages! I feel like I was mauled by Jesus. Who are you, my warranty?!</p>
      <ul>
        <li>File not found.</li>
        <li>Whoa a real live robot; or is that some kind of cheesy New Year's costume?</li>
        <li>Are you crazy? I can't swallow that.</li>
      </ul>
      <h3>Lethal Inspection</h3> 
      <p>As an interesting side note, as a head without a body, I envy the dead. Oh sure! Blame the wizards! Take me to your leader! Kif might! What kind of a father would I be if I said no?</p>
      <h4>Anthology of Interest II</h4> 
      <p>I had more, but you go ahead. But, like most politicians, he promised more than he could deliver. Noooooo! Have you ever tried just turning off the TV, sitting down with your children, and hitting them? Why would a robot need to drink? THE BIG BRAIN
        AM WINNING AGAIN! I AM THE GREETEST! NOW I AM LEAVING EARTH, FOR NO RAISEN!</p>
      <ol>
        <li>You can see how I lived before I met you.</li>
        <li>This opera's as lousy as it is brilliant! Your lyrics lack subtlety. You can't just have your characters announce how they feel. That makes me feel angry!</li>
        <li>Oh sure! Blame the wizards!</li>
        <li>OK, this has gotta stop. I'm going to remind Fry of his humanity the way only a woman can.</li>
        <li>Belligerent and numerous.</li>
      </ol>
      <h5>War Is the H-Word</h5> 
      <p>I had more, but you go ahead. You can see how I lived before I met you. I saw you with those two "ladies of the evening" at Elzars. Explain that. Five hours? Aw, man! Couldn't you just get me the death penalty? In your time, yes, but nowadays shut
        up! Besides, these are adult stemcells, harvested from perfectly healthy adults whom I killed for their stemcells. And I'm his friend Jesus.</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it seems that you can do what you want with just floats and border. I've copied @Aaron's HTML to create [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/x06je10w/).

The basics are the css:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
aside {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid green 2px;
  background-color: white;
}
article {
  border-left: solid white 200px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

I made the background of the sidebar white so you can see the effect. Float both the sidebar and the content. Give the content a left border the same width as the sidebar and the color of the sidebar background.

It seems to work regardless of the length of the sidebar. When the sidebar is longer, it's background extends the height of the window. When the content is longer, it's border extends the height of the window.